# Building .sif file from microarray ,tab file with expression valuses and gene id only

Tags: bioinformatics, bayesian-networks, medical, genetics, cytoscape

How to generate a `.sif (simple interaction)` file from gene micro array expression .tab file containing only gene expression values and gene names? I use Expander software and MeV and want to build an input file for `Cytoscape and Spike software`. Is there any R package or specific plugin or software for that purpose?

I can manually write .sif file based on precomputed correlation between genes:

```
CD31 pp CD34
BRCA pp CD31
VEGF pp CD34
```

However, don`t know how to generate it automatically using other metrics.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a sample of the .sif file you use to do manually the relation you posted? I am not used to these software. Also if your question is is there any X it is not under the guide of the site. Are you really trying to solve a programming problem ?

Comment: I need to build pathways from gene expression values. This is about data processing. Thanks.

Comment: Then we need some sample data to precess like you would like to show you how to do it.